# Pull to Refresh: data refresh is delayed

Tags: ios, swift, cloudkit, pull-to-refresh

I've got Pull to Refresh working great, except when the table reloads there is a split second delay before the data in the table reloads.

Do I just have some small thing out of place? Any ideas?

`viewDidLoad`:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.refreshControl?.addTarget(self, action: "handleRefresh:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.ValueChanged)
    self.getCloudKit()
}
```

`handleRefresh` for Pull to Refresh:

```
func handleRefresh(refreshControl: UIRefreshControl) {    
    self.objects.removeAll()
    self.getCloudKit()
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
        refreshControl.endRefreshing()
    })
}
```

Need the data in two places, so created a function for it `getCloudKit`:

```
func getCloudKit() {
    publicData.performQuery(query, inZoneWithID: nil) { results, error in
        if error == nil { // There is no error
            for play in results! {
                let newPlay = Play()
                newPlay.color = play["Color"] as! String
                self.objects.append(newPlay)
            }

            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            })

        } else {
            print(error)
        }
    }
}
```

`tableView`:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("reuseIdentifier", forIndexPath: indexPath)
    let object = objects[indexPath.row]
    if let label = cell.textLabel{
        label.text = object.matchup
    }
    return cell
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't call `endRefreshing` until just before you call `reloadData` in the dispatch block

Comment: @Paulw11 Thanks for the response! I think that makes sense now.  But how would I do that in the code I have, because I wouldn't want to put `endRefreshing` in my `getCloudKit` function right (because I only need to use `endRefreshing` for Pull To Refresh not `viewDidLoad` right?)?

Comment: You can call endRefreshing regardless. If the control,isn't in the refreshingg state it will just ignore it

Comment: @Paulw11 ok cool thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how you should do this:

1. In your `handleRefresh` function, add a bool to track the refresh operation in process - say `isLoading`.
2. In your `getCloudKit` function just before reloading the table view call `endRefreshing` function if `isLoading` was true.
3. Reset `isLoading` to `false`.
4. Importantly - Do not remove your model data before refresh operation is even instantiated. What if there is error in fetching the data? Delete it only after you get response back in `getCloudKit` function.
5. Also, as a side note, if I would you, I would implement a timestamp based approach where I would pass my last service data timestamp (time at which last update was taken from server) to server and server side would return me complete data only there were changes post that timestamp else I would expect them to tell me no change. In such a case I would simple call `endRefreshing` function and would not reload data on table. Trust me - this saves a lot and gives a good end user experience as most of time there is no change in data!